# Type of base ActiveRecords?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I'm writing a gem to extend the default Rails classes. I have already got it working for ActiveRecord::Relation, thought I would like it working for the generic class, but I can't identify its class type.

Currently I have:

`User.first.posts.test_method`

working, as User.first.posts.class.name == "ActiveRecord::Relation"

However, I can't figure out how to get this working:

`User.test_method`

and `User.class.name` just returns `Class` which isn't really helpful.

I've tried to extend into ActiveRecord::Base but with no luck. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def this_should_work
      "it does"
    end
  end
end

User.this_should_work
=> "it does"
```

Comment: It works! Two questions: 1) I'm trying to incorporate it using railties and ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, any tips on how to do that, and 2) Why does it work?!

Comment: I can't help you with Railtie, but this works because it reopen the ActiveRecord::Base class and defines a new class method. Once defined, any children of ActiveRecord::Base will be equipped with the method because of their inheritance.